# How do I configure Squid to block outbound traffic to specific IP and port ranges?

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm new to proxies and Squid so please bear with me.

I'm trying to make a quick and dirty proxy out of my raspi. I've got it set up so I can block certain websites/domains, but I need to be able to block outbound traffic to specific port ranges for specific IP ranges.

Is this even possible? Everything I've found so far is about blocking traffic from certain IP's and ports on your home network.

Edit: This is only going to be used by a few devices on my network, so there shouldn't be too much trouble with bottlenecks.